# protractor async await Cannot read property 'getTitle' of undefined

Tags: selenium-webdriver, async-await, protractor

I'm having issues with getting pageTitle with the following code:

```
async function test(){

            await global.browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com');
            console.log('555');
            console.log(await global.broswer.getTitle());

        }

        return test();
```

the sequence is browser launches and goes to yahoo, 555 is outputted, but then I get Failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTitle' of undefined.  I was thinking of putting an await sleep before the getTitle but it would return the same error with Cannot read property 'sleep' of undefined. Is there a problem with webdriverjs APIs?  Thanks.

Comment: what's `broswer`?

Comment: firefox 51.0.1.

Comment: isn't that a typo?

Comment: hi elrull which text are you referring to about typo?

Comment: `broswer` should be `browser`

Comment: omg! thanks..thats my fault.  sitting at the comp too long.

Comment: I would recommend closing your question, as this won't be helpful for others  searching for something similar

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the promise first.